# How to split contribution page into tabs

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, contribution-page

I would like to divide my contribution page into tabs: intro + priceset, payment information, submit section. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the standard CiviCRM contribution page I don't know if this is possible.
You can do this easily with Webform (on Drupal). Haven't tried yet but maybe Caldera forms (on WordPress) does the job.